# Developer Survey: What about Indonesians?

Tags: discussion

I am reading the 2017 Developer Survey [here](https://stackoverflow.com/insights/survey/2017/?utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=hero&utm_campaign=dev-survey-2017&utm_content=hero-ind-ques).  I got to the "Ethnicity" section.

If you are from Southeast Asia -- Indonesia for example, what category does one select?

Other countries that come to mind that do not fit these categories: Myanmar, Thailand, Cambodia, Laos, Viet Nam, Malaysia, Brunei, Singapore, Indonesia, East Timor, and Philippines.

In the context of the available list...

East Asia means to me: Mainland China, Hongkong, Macau, Taiwan, South and North Korea (ROK & DPRK), Japan.  Some people include Viet Nam or Mongolia, but that is complex.

South Asia means to me: India, Pakistan, Sri Lanka, Nepal, Bhutan, Maldives, and Bangladesh.

And what of Central Asia?  For our fellow StackOverflowers from Tajikistan... what would they select?  Do Pashtuns in Western Pakistan (FATA) select South Asian or Middle Eastern?  (Ok, I am trolling on that last one!)

This list appears to be similar to that used by the United States Census Bureau.

(Another way to ask this question would be to divide nationality from ethnicity, where nationality is probably your primary passport, but your ethnicity can be anything... Hello Singapore/London/São Paulo.)